# How do Fragtrap's Subroutines work?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

One of Fragtrap's skill trees, **Fragmented Fragtrap**, focuses on some Subroutines that give bonuses and penalties to different weapons.

How do **Subroutines** work, what are **Frag Stacks**, and how bad is **Tripleclocked**?

Comment: @FrankV I love them... while I play solo and have infinite time to swap weapons, plan my moves and generally adapt the pace of the game to current Sub. They force me to experience diverse things and work towards all the badass challenges. But as soon as I'm in coop, yeah, I just spec out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*General description, see math below*

Skills in **Fragmented Fragtrap** tree give immense bonuses to certain weapon types, while penalizing all others, incentivizing the player to switch weapons to match the current Subroutine.

Subroutines are time-based, each one being active for **100 seconds**. Frag Stacks are basically units of time - you are granted 100 Frag Stacks at Subroutine activation, and they decay at a rate of one per second. Down the skill tree there are skills that allow the player to prolong or shorten a Subroutine's duration as follows:

- Grenade Vent **adds** up to 5 Frag Stacks per **Grenade thrown**
- Cryogenic Exhaust Manifold **subtracts** up to 5 Frag Stacks on a **Slam**
- Float like a Bee **adds** up to 5 Frag Stacks on a **Melee Kill**

There are four skills that unlock different Subroutines, first two of which are mandatory, while other two are optional. **Only one** Subroutine is active at any time, and learning more skills just adds new Subroutines to the pool they are randomly picked from.

- **Gun Subroutines** increase Damage, Fire Rate and Reload Speed of a single gun type, while decreasing Damage of other gun types. Grenades and Melee are not affected.
- **Defensive Subroutines** increase Capacity and Regeneration of either Health or Shields, while decreasing Damage with all guns. Grenades and Melee are not affected.
- **Melee Subroutine** drastically increases Melee Damage, while decreasing Damage with all guns. Grenades are not affected.
- **Elemental Subroutines** increase Damage of a single element, while decreasing Damage of other elements. Grenades are affected, non-elemental guns and Melee are not.

The bonuses are pretty modest until you get **Tripleclocked** skill at level 14. It **multiplies** all bonuses and penalties of Subroutines by a varying factor of up to 3 depending on Frag Stack count - multiplier is x1 at 100 Frag Stacks and reaches x3 by Subroutine expiration.

Fortunately, negative modifiers in Borderlands are handled by an **asymptotic formula** of 1/(1-x) - that means that a penalty of -75% does not leave 25% of a value ("4 times less"), but 1/(1+0,75) = 57%. Considering this, here is a table of all possible bonuses or penalties of Subroutines:

```
                        Gun Damage  Fire Rate  Reload Speed  Wrong Gun Damage
Gun Subroutine             +25%        +20%        +20%            -13%
 Tripleclocked Max         +75%        +60%        +60%            -31%
                         Capacity  Regeneration                 Gun Damage
Defensive Subroutines      +35%      +2.5%/sec                     -13%
 Tripleclocked Max        +105%      +7.5%/sec                     -31%
                       Melee Damage                             Gun Damage
Melee Subroutine          +150%                                    -20%
 Tripleclocked Max        +450%                                    -43%
                      Element Damage                       Wrong Element Damage
Elemental Subroutines      +32%                                    -14%
 Tripleclocked Max         +96%                                    -32%
```

*Note: Tripleclocked Health and Shields always receive +105% Capacity, only Regeneration ramps up with Frag Stacks.*

Oh, and one more bit of math:

```
                        Gun DPS   Wrong Gun DPS
Gun Subroutine            +50%        -13%
 Tripleclocked Max       +180%        -31%
```

Comment: Tediore reloads are grenades, and are not affected by bonuses or penalties to bullet damage.

Comment: Do they count as grenades as far as Grenade Vent is concerned?

Comment: @Unionhawk Yes, totally, all grenade bonuses affect Tediore reloads.

Comment: I have re-read the question and only now realized Unionhawk may have asked about if reloading a Tediore gives Frag Stacks. No, it doesnt, "reloading a Tediore" doesn't count as "throwing a grenade". But the projectile that reloading results in is considered a grenade, and gains damage bonus.